# Import Inventory Item from Excel to Sage 50 using window scheduled task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, system-administration, sage-line-50

How can i import Inventory Items from EXcel to Sage 50 or vise versa automatically using Window Task Scheduler or something similar, without using 3rd Party Application?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this using windows scheduler without a 3rd party application, the only option to import data to Sage 50 is via the File > Import menu option using CSV files and this cannot be scheduled by any external application.

I suppose you could write a CBT hook to send messages to Sage to drive this but the amount of development effort involved in doing this you may as well buy a 3rd party app.

There are plenty of 3rd party apps on the market I won't mention any here but just google anything like "sage integration" and there are a few that will do this job for you.

HTH
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Workaround.  If your import is standard flow of keystrokes, you could use Autohotkey to write up a macro that would  do this for you.   The scheme I would think would start from a standard desktop profile, where Sage 50 is in a predictable position and available every time the macro is run.

1) Copy the Excel sheet you want to import to a directory where AHK will find it.  Of course with named ranges and such prepared and mapped for Sage 50

2) write an AHK script to process the following.
- Test if the excel file is in the "transfer" directory
- Select Sage 50
- Send the complete keystroke selecting each many item function, may be selecting a head menu item, and then a number of down keystrokes, tabs etc. or other gestures to select items needed.
- run the import.
- After successful completion, move the Excel file from the "transfer" directory to a "completed transfers" directory

Autohotkey is a very powerful   tool, and there are great support forums here regarding it.  If you do not know about it you should!  Google it.   Good luck.